# Add a feature to alert for new questions in chatrooms

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

I suggest a new feature:

- A room may get some tags assigned, if a new question (or answer, whatever) gets posted on parent site, there will be an alert. For instance: I set "anything which has both tags [c] and [memory-leak]", then A small message will be postet by some kind of bot to this room. It may be also possible to arrange this for single questions only.

This feature would be very useful in the way, that you don't have to leave the chatroom to get alerted about news, thus can focus yourself on the discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For user-specific questions, my advice would be to use a separate RSS (or similar) tool. Or just scan the questions occasionally ;p Who knows, something interesting might be there that *doesn't* have the right tags.

For room-specific questions: that feature already exists; room-owners can elect to associate one or more feeds, typically the new-question feed for a given tag, with the room. In most cases *for question feeds* it is preferable to use the "ticker" view for this, which causes a small panel to appear with new questions as they appear (without disrupting the flow). In fact, that is how I saw **this** question appear:[image]

Comment: Thx. I didn't saw this.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to get notified not only about the tags of the chat room I am in at the moment, but maybe questions within my interested tags. Yet that would be most intrusive for other chatters in the room.

Thinking your request through I would then need a feature to answer questions without leaving the chat room. And to see answers given to these questions so I don't duplicate replies or can learn something new while chatting away. As you can see, this goes too far, in my opinion.

Why not have the StackExchange Inbox feature in chat as well, and enhance it to notify me about new questions I am interested in (maybe in blue instead of red)?